# Вставка в кадр даты ffmpeg java

Tags: java, ffmpeg, javacv

Пишу видео с rtsp потока

```
while (running && ((frame =grabber.grab()) != null)) {
            recorder.record(frame);
```

Все работает и все сохраняется хорошо! Можно ли вставить в видео строку с текущей датой? И как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по коду, используется JavaCV. Строчку для фильтра вам уже дали, а дальше вам нужно воспользоваться

```
org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameFilter
```

См: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bytedeco/javacv/FFmpegFrameFilter.java

Это интерфейс к libavfilter. Собственно его документацию и документацию на прочие фильтры вам стоит почитать.

Скорее всего подойдёт что-то вроде:

```
FrameFilter filter = FrameFilter.createDefault("drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf:text='%T': fontcolor=white@0.8: x=7: y=460", width, height);
while (running && ((frame = grabber.grab()) != null)) {
  filter.push(frame);
  while (running && ((filteredFrame = filter.pull()) != null)) {
    recorder.record(filteredFrame);
  }
}
```

Более того, вам можно реализовать свой фильтр, расширив

```
org.bytedeco.javacv.FrameFilter
```

но это в случае, когда хочется чего-то, чего не умеет FFmpeg.

**UPD:** для старых версий (API < 1.0):

1) из IplFrame получить BufferedImage, выдержка из README.md:

FAQ about IplImage:

- For custom raw processing of data, createBuffer() returns an NIO
  direct;
- buffer wrapped around the memory pointed by imageData, and
  under Android we can;
- also use that Buffer with
  Bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer() and copyPixelsToBuffer();
- To get a BufferedImage from an IplImage, we may call getBufferedImage();
- The createFrom() factory method can construct an IplImage from a
  BufferedImage;
- There are also a few copy*() methods for BufferedImage<->IplImage data transfers.

2) Врисовать туда, что вам нужно (гуглить: draw text on buffered image), например: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658554/using-graphics2d-to-overlay-text-on-a-bufferedimage-and-return-a-bufferedimage

3) Сконвертировать обратно в IplFrame (см. п.1)

PS не программист на Java, просто неплохо владею FFmpeg :-)

Comment: я использую библиотеку javacv 0.10 как я понял в ней нет FrameFilter. Версию поменять не могу

Comment: Я полагаю и связанный JavaCpp и javacpp-presets у вас тоже 0.10? В таком случае используйте стандартные доступные способы. У вас есть frame (IplFrame), из него можно получить BufferedImage (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368078/java-bufferedimage-to-iplimage), в котомро уже нарисовать всё, что вам нужно средствами Java (гуглить: draw text on buffered image, например: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658554/using-graphics2d-to-overlay-text-on-a-bufferedimage-and-return-a-bufferedimage). Либо получить при помощи as
CvMat() матрицу, которую можно процессить средсвами OpenCV.

Comment: Вот выдержка из README.md: FAQ about IplImage:
        1) For custom raw processing of data, createBuffer() returns an NIO direct;
        2)   buffer wrapped around the memory pointed by imageData, and under Android we can;
        3) also use that Buffer with Bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer() and copyPixelsToBuffer();
        4) To get a BufferedImage from an IplImage, we may call getBufferedImage();
        5) The createFrom() factory method can construct an IplImage from a BufferedImage;
        6) There are also a few copy*() methods for BufferedImage<->IplImage data transfers.

Comment: Спасибо! Это помогло!